# How to match a word without space with ElasticSearch data having space

Tags: elasticsearch

In my elasticsearch I had data "New York", I want to query and match "NewYork" (please note no space in query string). How can I achieve this? Is there any analyzer that can help here?

Comment: Why don't you try some analyzer that removes space while storing date. Have a look at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern-replace-charfilter.html, what is you can replace ' '(space) with ''(no space)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you can apply to [Shingle Token Filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-shingle-tokenfilter.html). The shingle filter will create new tokens by concatenating adjacent terms. A part of your query can look like as:

```
...
"my_shingle":{
   "type":"shingle",
   "max_shingle_size":5,
   "min_shingle_size":2,
   "output_unigrams":"true",
   token_separator: ""
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to use the Shingle Token Filter to obtain the desired result.

https://arjunjs.wordpress.com/2017/04/02/elasticsearch-how-to-search-for-a-word-without-spaces-if-word-itself-is-combination-of-two-different-words/

Hope this helps.